# How to speed up the first load of this EF query, seems to be issue with TPH Inheritance and GetExecutionPlan?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I have EF5 with MS SQL2008.

I have a query :

```
if (db.Class.OfType<I_Header>().Any(c => c.RId == myRId))
```

It is using TBH inheritance and with the derived class of "I_Header" descending from the base class of "Class".

The initial load time is 10 secs. The second load time is 50ms.

I have used DotTrace to provide more information and the following is the culprit:

```
System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable[MergeOption])
```

I have pregenerated the EF Views, but this has not affected this query.

Any thoughts on how I can remove this initial performance hit?

Thanks in advance.

---

For now I have implemented a warmup routine in the Session_Start event which initialises the relevant object which includes the relevant LINQ code. It does work, although it would be nicer to be able to precompile.

---

If I alter this query as such:

```
if (db.Class.Any(c => c.RId == myRId))
```

The Query compile time is now 1 sec.

The discriminator used to create this inheritance is pretty simple ie ClassType = "I". I have even put a non clustered index on this column in MS SQL2008, but to no effect.

So clearly it is TPH that is affecting it so much. However I do need to use TPH as my next query fills a variable of type "I_Header" not "Class".

**To do with TPH inheritance**

I think the issue is to with TPH inheritance. Here is my EDMX fragments:

TPH Entity definition

```
        <EntityType Name="I_Test" BaseType="MyApp.Models.ED.Class" devart:InheritanceType="TablePerHierarchy" ed:InheritanceGuid="db77288f-5c72-4cd1-804d-89ae7ae5a9a5" ed:Guid="8220c9e2-8b07-42d0-8a70-21222cdc59fc">
      <Property Name="Col1" Type="String" Nullable="false" ed:ValidateRequired="True" ed:Guid="8ca5b53b-e50f-451e-b14f-6d3ce2ba3fcb" />
    </EntityType>
```

TPH Mapping to Base Class:

```
            <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="MyApp.Models.ED.I_Test">
          <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="Classes">
            <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Id" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="RId" ColumnName="RId" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="CHId" ColumnName="CHId" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="Lid" ColumnName="Lid" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="Mode" ColumnName="Mode" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="SId" ColumnName="SId" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="DateUpdated" ColumnName="DateUpdated" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="Col1" ColumnName="S1" />
            <Condition ColumnName="ClassType" Value="IT" />
          </MappingFragment>
        </EntityTypeMapping>
```

Does not look that complicated, so quite weird why it is taking so long.

**Web.config EF settings**

```
<configSections>
  <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
```

Connection Strings:

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=myServer\mssql2008;Initial Catalog=myDB;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="MyAppEntitiesConnectionString" connectionString="metadata=res://MyApp.Models.ED/MyApp.csdl|res://MyApp.Models.ED/MyApp.ssdl|res://MyApp.Models.ED/MyApp.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=myServer\mssql2008;Initial Catalog=MyApp;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Assemblies:

```
    <compilation debug="true" defaultLanguage="c#" maxBatchGeneratedFileSize="4000" maxBatchSize="4000" targetFramework="4.5">
       <assemblies>
          <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Entity Framework Section:

```
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
```

**My .NET Version**

```
.NET 4.5

System.Data.Entity 
  - Runtime Version : v4.0.30319
  - Version : 4.0.0.0
```

Comment: As far as I can tell you can't precompile individual queries at compile time, it happens once at runtime and the result is then cached by EF internally (for EF >= 5.0). 10 seconds for such a simple query is *really* a long time. Do you have "a lot" of entities derived from the base `Class`? (But I'm not even sure if that matters for the performance of query translation.)

Comment: @Slauma, Many thanks for the reply. I have a derived class that is made up of complex types in addition to the inherited properties which is simple types ie integer, string etc. In one case I have about 6 complex types each with about 4 simple type ie string. Each of these simple properties map to a generic storage column ie Address may map to S1 (string). It may be this combination of TPH and complex types that is causing EF so much pain. I am going to break it down, and try a derived TPH class with simple types and then build it up to see if this is the case.

Comment: You say one cannot precompile queries, but there is "CompileQuery", which I understand from EF5 is less relevant due to the one off compilation and caching. I am also wondering whether I would do mys4lf any favours by going to EF6.1, although there is a side effect in that EF.dll is not native, as I understand it, so ones has to NGen this or suffer an initial hit. I am running on Azure Websites, so I am unsure whether I can use NGen at all.

Comment: `CompiledQuery` doesn't translate the query *at compile time* but when it is called for the first time *at runtime*. Then it is cached again. (It basically was the older way of triggering the caching mechanism manually which, since EF 5, happens automatically.) It most likely won't save you from the performance hit at the first call. I doubt that EF 6.1 will solve the problem. I didn't read anything that query translation has been improved so significantly over EF 5. Somehow I suspect the problem is somewhere else. 10 sec is too long for this simple query.

Comment: BTW: What if you call *first* some completely different query on another table for example and directly *after that* your query in question? Does your query still take 10 sec? If not, the problem is not compilation of individual queries, but more likely your EF view pregeneration failed for some reason.

Comment: A bit more research. 10 secs was achieved using pregeneratored views, and 38 secs without. So pregenerated views definately helps overall. However there is obviously an underlying issue which I need to research more deeply. I will also try your suggestion above

Comment: @Slauma, just test your suggestion. No difference. Must be something to do with the TPH and complex types. Going to test with a new test TPH but with simple types and then build it up.

Comment: It is to do with TPH inheritance. Just added a simple one string property derived class and it takes another 10 secs !!!

Comment: What is this `devart:...` attribute in your EDMX? Do you use another provider than the MS SQLClient provider? Something from DevArt? But database is MS SQL Server, right?

Comment: @Slauma, Yes well spotted. I use Devart's Entity Developer Model Designer. So all the POCOs and EDMX is produced from this tool. In addition the tool pregenerated the Views if required into standard *.PregeneratedViews.cs file. I have also fired the question to them and pointed them to this SO post. However I do believe I am using the standard MS SQLClient provider. How can I check this? I am currently checking my web.config and will post what I find.

Comment: I have now posted more information on my configuration, as extra EDITs in the main question body, and cannot spot anything untoward. Thanks again.

Comment: You are apparently using SqlClient as provider. I've made a little test program (one base class, 6 derived classes, EF 5, .NET 4.5, Code-First) and for your `OfType<...>() / Any(...)` query I get 17 milliseconds. Almost no difference between first and second call which is what I would expect for such a simple query. I'm afraid that you must cook down the model to a simpler test case (or start from a simple model and build it up) to find at which point the bad performance occurs. Right now I really have no idea where those 10 sec could come from. It's definitely not "normal" TPH behaviour.

Comment: @Slauma, really appreciate this help.Confirmation that that there is no issue with EF5, .NET4.5, is good. Would there be any difference with the fact that I am taking a model first approach, and producing POCOs which I believe are used in conjunction with the EDMX (named as *.edml). If you would like to create an answer as a recommendation then I can mark it up. You have been most helpful. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, does my web.config stuff look fine?

Comment: Web.config looks OK as far as I can see. I can't really write a reasonable answer. I propose to just leave the question open. Maybe someone else has a good idea or if you find the reason yourself you could write it as a brief answer.

Comment: @Slauma, Done some more testing with the very excellent Miniprofiler which I have just discovered. It appears to be a problem with my base class which maps onto a table with about 125 columns. The test base classes has about 5 and compiled in 50ms ish time. So would having 125 columns in the base table be the source of my problem? Also note that the derived class may only use say 30 properties which mean it will only be mapped to 30 base table columns. The underlying base table is generic in nature and I am using EF to map domain relevant entities to generic storage entites ie Table columns.